# Has the floating calendar icon feature and "Aa" button been removed from Google Sheets on Android?

Tags: google, calendar

I found a screenshot of the buttons I am trying to describe on [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138996/insert-todays-date-in-google-sheets) other post. Thanks.

But the actual feature is no longer appearing on my app. I recently updated it (8 Jun 2021) so I'm worried that it's been removed.

Anybody know?

[image]

Comment: I'm such a fool... Please forgive me... I found it! I panicked because my understanding was that it was a feature introduced recently and I thought perhaps it had been removed already but thank God... No, it is still there! You just need to click the input field and it appears. (Cringe)

Answer (score 0):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Eureka!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f33wG.jpg

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your answer. Please do not just post a screen shot also describe what it means and what steps are necessary.